# Can't figure out how to scroll down/up by 50px in js when i click a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is the code I have currently. What I want to do, is when I click a button - Move up- I want the text in `area3` to move up by `50px`. But right now its moving all the way back up to the top. This is for a h/w assignment and we're doing pretty basic js/jquery if that needs to be said? :) Any help will be appreciated! Thanks!

```js
$("#moveUp").click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var scrollPos = $(".area").scrollTop();
  var newPos = scrollPos - 50;
  $(".area3").scrollTop(newPos);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="area3">
 blah blah
</div>
<div class="area4">
  <button id="moveUp">Move Up</button>
</div>
```

Comment: $(".area").scrollTop(); shuld be: $(".area3").scrollTop();

Comment: Could you clarify you question I am not sure if you want to scroll the screen or just to move element 50px up?

Comment: @NedkoDimitrov just the text inside the div. its a couple of paragraphs worth of text

Comment: @PoulBak That was it! Thank you!!!   Its infuriating how a little typo can make you go mad for hours! haha :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#moveUp").click(function(event){
    window.scrollTo(0, window.scrollY - 50)
})
```

window.scrollTo(x, y) is a method which will scroll the screen to given coordinates where **x** is horizontal and **y** vertical. The top left corner of the screen is **0, 0**. Than window.scrollY gets the current vertical position of the screen, you just need to subtract 50 to scroll 50px up from your current position

Comment: Missing `);` at the end of your event handler **=>** `});`

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong, I think this could help you:

```
$("#moveup").click(function(){
        $(".area3").css({"margin-top":"-=50px"});
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want just the `text` in `area3` to move you should use some `css` to correctly implement this behavior with `jQuery`, using `animate()` to add some `ease` with smooth animation to the *text*.

```js
$("#moveUp").click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  $('.area3').animate({
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: +50
  }, 'slow');
})
```

```css
.area3 {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
}

.area3 span {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="area3">
  <span>blah blah</span>
</div>
<div class="area4">
  <button id="moveUp">Move Up</button>
</div>
```

but if you want the whole *window* to `scroll` you can do that as following we using the same approach with different *selectors* `body` and `html`

```js
$("#moveUp").click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  $('body, html').animate({
    scrollTop: -50
  }, 500);
})
```

```css
body, html {
  height: 1000px
}
.area3 {
  margin-top: 100px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="area3">
  <span>blah blah</span>
</div>
<div class="area4">
  <button id="moveUp">Move Up</button>
</div>
```

if you wanna to do it with `window` *interface* you can occur that by changing the above code to

```
$("#moveUp").click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  window.scrollTo(0, -50);
})
```

with this approach using `window` you can make it moving smoothly like we did above you can't use *jQuery* `animate()` `API` javascript gonna raise an error don't do that.